# Wordpress Admin 404s on dedicated server

Tags: linux, wordpress, cpanel, whm

So I have a dedicated server from Host Gator. Pretty large amount of space as well as resources. I have about 200 low budget, nothing really doing type of wordpess sites on the server.

I recently ran into an issue where when I try to go to the admin panel of any of the sites I get a 404 error on the front end of the sites. If I reboot the server or apache it works (sometimes).

Wondering if this could be some kind if htaccess issue or if I just have too many sites on the server now.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/  or http://ServerFault.com/ (professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite few solutions to tackle this issue. First you can go for a plugin if you want:

- [WordPress Quickie: Custom Query String Plugin](http://paulstamatiou.com/wordpress-quickie-custom-query-string-plugin)

Or code manually, check out this post:

- [Passing Query String Parameters in WordPress URL](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/)

Also check out:

- [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)